# Trying to create a setter method for my wrapper class matrix

Tags: java, matrix, setter

I have defined a own class, which implements a Wrapper class matrix for a 2-dimnesional Array. With a setter-method 'set(int n, int m, double d)' I want to set/change the value at the position n(row),m(colum) into d.

```
public class Matrix {

double matrix [][];
int matrixSize;

public Matrix(int matrixSize){
    this.matrix = new double [matrixSize][matrixSize];
}

public void setMatrixSize(int size){
    matrixSize = size;
}

public int getMatrixSize(){
    return matrixSize;
}

public void set(int n, int m, double d){
    double matrix [n][m] = d;
}}
```

I know, that my last method does not work, but I don't really know how to set the value double d at the array matrix at the position n, m.

If some of you may can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: The last method is almost fine, just remove the "double". You have already defined the type (it's a member)!

What doesn't work in your code is the `setMatrixSize`-Method, since an array has a fixed size (you change the member "matrixSize" but the array stays the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method set (for matrix) you define a new matrix which has nothing in common with matrix from the class, it's function's 2D array, not array from the class.

You probably want to do this:

```
    public void set(int n, int m, double d){
        this.matrix [n][m] = d;
    }
```

By using this.property, you say you're using property from the class and not from the method.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Fix the `set` method like this:

```
public void set(int n, int m, double d){
    this.matrix[n][m] = d;
}
```